# Setting up event handlers for buttons in Javascript / HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to set up event handlers for all “Add” buttons.

Comment: Any javascript code ?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

are you fine with a Vanilla JS snippet?
Something along these lines would do:

```
function registerHandlers () {
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
  [].slice.call(buttons).forEach(function (button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
  });
}

function onClick (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var button = event.target;
  var id = button.id;
  var desc = document.getElementById(id + '-img').getAttribute('title');
  var qty = document.getElementById(id + '-qty').value;

  addToTable(desc, qty);
}

function addToTable (desc, qty) {
  var row = '<tr><td align="left">' + desc + '</td><td align="right">' + qty + '</td></tr>';
  var tbody = document.querySelector('#orderlist tbody');
  tbody.innerHTML = tbody.innerHTML + row;
}

registerHandlers();
```

The code is untested :-)
But here's how it works:

registerHandlers:

1. Find all elements on the page which have the class "button" (via CSS Selector)
2. Turn the results from a NodeList into an Array using [[].slice.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like_objects).
3. Go over the list and register an event listener for "click"s on that element.

onClick:

1. Stop the default behaviour of the browser.
2. Determine the clicked button by inspecting the [target property of an event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).
3. Get the associated ID attribute's value.
4. Build the selector string for the image, [search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) the whole document for it. Read the `title` attribute of the found image. (This can crash if no such element was found).
5. Same with the Quantity.
6. Update the table.

addToTable:

1. Build a string with the `desc` and `qty` in between. You might want to put more effort by using [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) or [DOMParser](https://davidwalsh.name/convert-html-stings-dom-nodes) and get some sanity checks that way.
2. Find the `<tbody>` of the orderlist.
3. Append it's `innerHTML` with your new row.

Finally call registerHandler to make the above work.